# Converting .NEF to .JPG

Tags: conversion, jpeg

I am trying to convert .NEF files to .JPG and I am using the command:

```
mogrify -format JPG *.NEF
```

this produces

```
mogrify: delegate failed `"ufraw-batch" --silent --create-id=also --out-    type=png --out-depth=16 "--output=%u.png" "%i"' @ error/delegate.c/InvokeDelegate/1329.
mogrify: unable to open image `/tmp/magick-9036lhDZz9AOJ7G2.ppm': No such file or directory @ error/blob.c/OpenBlob/2695
```

When I try imagemagick:

```
convert DSC0001.NEF DSC0001.JPG
```

It produces

```
 --out-depth=16 "--output=%u.png" "%i"' @ error/delegate.c/InvokeDelegate/1329.
convert: unable to open image `/tmp/magick-9072zxFEis0gPDVe.ppm': No such file or directory @ error/blob.c/OpenBlob/2695.
convert: no images defined `DSC0001.JPG' @ error/convert.c/ConvertImageCommand/3212.
```

What is being told in this error message?

Comment: It can't find [`ufraw-batch`](http://ufraw.sourceforge.net/) (a delegate program that IM uses to read/convert your NEFs) so make sure you have it installed.

Comment: what distribution are you using?

Answer (score 11):

I had a similar problem doing a basic convert and I had to install the following package:

ufraw-batch

Comment: `ufraw-batch --out-type jpeg *` in directory where you have all your files

Answer (score 8):

Had the same problem this worked

```
sudo apt-get install ufraw-batch
mogrify -format jpg *.NEF
```