# Convert NEF to JPG with optimal brightness

Tags: conversion, imagemagick, brightness, mogrify

There are multiple tools for converting Nikon raw images (.NEF) to JPEG, as well as there are multiple discussions on this topic (e.g. [Converting .NEF to .JPG](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/226900/converting-nef-to-jpg/283791)). My question regards optimal settings for nice output images.

I have a bunch of NEF files. When I open them in Gwenview (4.14.0 pre), they look great. In that application, I can save them as JPEGs individually. The output files look the same (i.e. fine), but it does not seem to provide a way to do it in batch. Saving the files one by one is nonsense.

So I'd like to use a bash tool. Anyway, if I convert the images with `mogrify -format JPG *.NEF` or `convert DSC0001.NEF DSC0001.JPG` (see the aforementioned discussion), the output files are pretty dark. **I wonder what parameters should be used to achieve the same (or at least similar) results, compared to Gwenview.** (Not really sure how Gwenview detects the "optimal" settings - NEF metadata? Math?)